# Update List Values in Data Frame Based on Beginning of String and Merge ID

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a list of strings in a column of a data frame and I need to update the values in some of the rows that have missing values with the values of another row. The strings that needs to be updated will match the first and sometimes second word, and what dictates what needs to be changed in that subset of the data frame is a merge ID. I have a small snippet of the data frame and desired output below.

| merge id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [apple] |
| 1 | [apple tree, river fish 123] |
| 1 | [river] |
| 2 | [foo bar 111] |
| 2 | [foo bar, apple 888] |
| 2 | [apple] |

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'merge id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'values': [['apple'], ['apple tree', 'river fish 123'], ['river'], ['foo bar 111'], ['foo bar', 'apple 888'], ['apple']]
})
```

The desired output would be:

| merge id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [apple tree] |
| 1 | [apple tree, river fish 123] |
| 1 | [river fish 123] |
| 2 | [foo bar 111] |
| 2 | [foo bar 111, apple 888] |
| 2 | [apple 888] |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
from itertools import groupby


def fn(x):
    tmp = sorted(v for l in x["values"] for v in l)
    m = {}
    for _, g in groupby(tmp, cmp_to_key(lambda k1, k2: not k2.startswith(k1))):
        g = list(g)
        for v in g:
            m[v] = g[-1]
    x["values"] = [[m[v] for v in l] for l in x["values"]]
    return x


df = df.groupby("merge id", group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   merge id                        values
0         1                  [apple tree]
1         1  [apple tree, river fish 123]
2         1              [river fish 123]
3         2                 [foo bar 111]
4         2      [foo bar 111, apple 888]
5         2                   [apple 888]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very surprised if this can be done with vectorisation. As it stands, I did this the old fashioned way- using dictionaries, lists, and a few for loops:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'merge id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'values': [['apple'], ['apple tree', 'river fish 123'], ['river'], ['foo bar 111'], ['foo bar', 'apple 888'], ['apple']]
})
# group by merge id and make the values into a list
vals = df.groupby('merge id')['values'].apply(list).reset_index()

out = pd.DataFrame()
def clean_list(l, d):
    out = []
    for item in l:
        # if item is a list, recurse
        if isinstance(item, list):
            out.append(clean_list(item, d))
        else:
            # otherwise append the value from the dictionary
            out.append(d[item])
    return out

for r in vals.iterrows():
    # generate a sorted flattened list of all the values 
    flat_v = [item for sublist in r[1][1] for item in sublist]
    flat_v.sort(key=len)

    # initialise the dictionary, with every value pointing to itself
    d = {k: k for k in flat_v}

    # then go through each value, and every value after it, and if the first value is in the second value,
    # then set the first value to point to the second value
    for i in range(len(flat_v)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(flat_v)):
            if flat_v[i] in flat_v[j]:
                d[flat_v[i]] = flat_v[j]
                break
    # concatenate the new output with the out dataframe
    out = pd.concat([out, pd.DataFrame({'merge id': [r[1][0]], 'values': [clean_list(r[1][1], d)]})])

out.explode('values').reset_index(drop=True)

# Output:
   merge id                        values
0         1                  [apple tree]
1         1  [apple tree, river fish 123]
2         1              [river fish 123]
3         2                 [foo bar 111]
4         2      [foo bar 111, apple 888]
5         2                   [apple 888]
```